# Wake On Lan for Fedora 12

Tags: linux, networking, fedora

I have a fedora 12 box that I am using as a sandbox for web development and a few other toys.

The box gets really hot so I would like it to sleep/hibernate when no one is using it, however most of the people connecting to the box will not be able to access it physically.

Is it possible to set up a Wake On Lan that wakes up the machine when it detects an SSH connection?

A google search didn't yield much information. (or atleast I wasn't smart enough to register it as useful!)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to do that without something else in between that would answer the SSH request, and then issue the wake-on-lan to the destination machine.  In other words, there has to be something always up for SSH, and then you would issue the wake-up command from that box and SSH to your destination.  If you have a Linksys router (like the wrt54g/l) with the [tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/firmware) firmware installed on it, you can accomplish this using just the router with SSH enabled by SSHing into the router, running /usr/bin/ether-wake destination-mac-address and then sshing to the machine you just powered on.

Comment: I can also have him explicitly send the WOL command before sshing

but I still dont know how to configure the F12 box to support WOL

Comment: The WOL on the target machine is hardware dependant, there is nothing to enable on the OS side.  It would have to be enabled in the system BIOS.